# Having trouble figuring out how loss was calculated for SQuAD task in BERT paper

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, loss-function

The BERT Paper

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf

Section 4.2 covers the SQuAD training.

So from my understanding, there are two extra parameters trained, they are two vectors with the same dimension as the hidden size, so the same dimensions as the contextualized embeddings in BERT. They are S (for start) and E (for End).

For each, a softmax is taken with S and each of the final contextualized embeddings to get a score for the correct Start position. And the same thing is done for E and the correct end position.

I get up to this part. But I am having trouble figuring out how the did the labeling and final loss calculations, which is described in this paragraph

"and the maximum scoring span is used as the prediction. The training objective is the loglikelihood of the correct start and end positions."

What do they mean by "maximum scoring span is used as the prediction"?

Furthermore, how does that play into "The training objective is the loglikelihood of the correct start and end positions"?

From this Source:

https://ljvmiranda921.github.io/notebook/2017/08/13/softmax-and-the-negative-log-likelihood/

It says the log-likelihood is only applied to the correct classes. So the we are only calculating the softmax for the correct positions only, Not any of the in correct positions.

If this interpretation is correct, then the loss will be

```
Loss = -Log( Softmax(S*T(predictedStart) / Sum(S*Ti) ) -Log( Softmax(E*T(predictedEnd) / Sum(S*Ti) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it sounds like for every position $i$ in the input text the model predicts $$p_S(i) = \mathbb P(\text{correct start position is } i)$$ and $$p_E(i) = \mathbb P(\text{correct end position is } i).$$
Now let $\hat s = \arg\max_i p_S(i)$ and $\hat e = \arg\max_i p_E(i)$ be the most probable start and end positions (according to the model).

Then by "maximum scoring span is used as the prediction" they just mean that they output $(\hat e, \hat s)$ when predicting.

Then “The training objective is the loglikelihood of the correct start and end positions” means that if the correct start and end positions are $s^*$ and $e^*$, they try to maximize the predicted probability of $s^*$ and $e^*$. If the start and end positions are independent then this is equal to $p_S(s^*) p_E(e^*)$ and taking the negative log the loss becomes
$$L(e^*, s^*) = -\log p_S(s^*) -\log p_E(e^*).$$